# Why the character become strange after auto rig?

Tags: rigging, bones, rigid-body-simulation

[image]

[image]

[image]

I made a model in blender, try to rig it with bone created by myself.

It became screwy in some places(Hip,Shoulder...), I have meet this problem many days.

My File is here.
[image]

I follow the tutorials on Youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkuOs_VA_y4&t=296s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBYb1YmaOMY

Comment: Hello, please share the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have shared the file. Thank you very much